# Android Jquery Mobile disable white input box Overlays.

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova, jquery-mobile, htcsense

I developed an ios App in Phonegap using Jquery Mobile. It worked perfectly. So I decided to turn it into an Android App, thinking it wouldn't be that difficult, just a few tweaks here and there...

First lesson learned, it isn't. After having to upgrade to the beta version of Jquery Mobile and upgrading Jquery. I got the text inputs 'working' a problem I described here :

[HTML form Input with Phonegap Android development in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12371426/html-form-input-with-phonegap-android-development-in-eclipse)

But now when I click on a text input box, like an email field, I am presented with what seems like an overlayed white textbox, that isn't even aligned. It seems to highlight my input field, then display another white unstyled one, that I haven't asked it to.

I am using:

```
jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js
jquery.mobile-1.2.0-beta.1.min.js
jquery.mobile-1.2.0-beta.1.min.css

And cordova 2.0
```

I have tried all solutions in here:

[Disable Android browser's input overlays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9423101/disable-android-browsers-input-overlays)

But none of them work. I am working from an android HTC. Has anyone else had this problem? Or know how to disable android from displaying another white input box and just use the one I've provided.

Any help would be appreciated.